# Evaluate computed property inside a function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying this in script section in .vue file:

```
<template>...    
<script>
    
    const checkType = (value) => {
      // Need to know transferType value
      console.log(this.transferType)

      if (!value) {
        return false
      }
    
      return true
    }
    
    export default {
     data: () => ({/*some data*/}),
     computed: {
      transferType() {
       if (this.$store.state.transfer.type === 'one way') return true
       return false
      }
     }
    }
</script>
```

How can I evaluate the value of computed property **transferType** in **checkType** function?

I will appreciate any help

Comment: is there a reason that checkType isn't a computed function on your vue instance?

Comment: or added as a mixin

Comment: `transferType() {return checkType(this.$store.state.transfer.type)}`

Comment: @maembe yes, I use checkType for custom vuelidate validation, so I need to know transfer type to make return date required

Answer (score 0):

Import store into your script, and access it there instead of from your component instance.

```js
import store from './store'

const checkType () {
      return store.state.transfer.type === 'one way'
}
```